# Class "app\Exports\ProyectoExport" not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-excel

i got a variable with info i pull from a data base, and when i try to use the command:
`return Excel::download(new ProyectoExports ($resultados), 'nombre_archivo.xlsx');`
i get the error: Class` "app\Exports\ProyectoExports" not found

this is my code

controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use app\Exports\ResultadosExport;
use app\Exports\ProyectoExport;

public function descargarExcel(Request $request)
    {
      $resultados = session('resultados');
      return Excel::download(new ProyectoExports ($resultados), 'nombre_archivo.xlsx');   
    }
```

ProyectoExport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;


use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class ProyectoExport implements FromCollection
{
   /**
   * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
   */
   protected $resultados;

   public function __construct(Collection $resultados)
   {
       $this->resultados = $resultados;
   }

   public function collection()
   {
       return $this->resultados;
   }
}
```

i tried uninstalling the maatwebsite and installing again, tried to use compose dump-autoload

Comment: Are `app\Exports` and `App\Exports` the same namespace?

Comment: I don’t know exactly what you mean but yeah i supose they are the same namespace

Comment: Try `App\Exports` instead of `app\Exports`

Comment: it worked, thanks man but why tha folders name is app no App

Comment: The `app` folder is autoloaded with the `App`  namespace in the `composer.json` file.